# How to get a model's ID in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I have a model defined as follows:

```
App.Product = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    price: DS.attr('number') 
});
```

The REST endpoint successfully returns products, however, despite also returning a field named 'id' containing an integer alongside name and price, it doesn't allow me to retrieve this ID.

```
product1 = this.store.find('Product', 1);
console.log(product1.get('name'); // successful
console.log(product1.get('id'); // undefined
```

(I tried adding `id: DS.attr('number')` but Ember doesn't allow this.)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find` is [promise-aware](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.RSVP.Promise.html): you should be able to check the id like this:

```
promise = this.store.find('product', '1').then(function(product) {
  console.log(product.get('id'));
});
```

Also make sure you haven't changed your adapter's `primaryKey' property to something other than`id`.